# How to use Sequelize to get list of fields and their types of a model

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, model, sequelize.js

For example, if I have a User model with defined fields: {name, location, dob, value}. Is there anyway I can get a list of such data out of a model? Maybe even something like

```
[ {var: "name" , type: "string" }, 
{var: "location" , type: "string" }, 
{var: "dob" , type: "date" }, 
{var: "value" , type: "int" },
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update [27/03/2024]**
In v7+ rawAttributes has been deprecated.
Use .modelDefinition.attributes. In OP case User.modelDefinition.attributes

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/54f1e18748180b72da045066d7a5798f12cb1beb/packages/core/src/model-typescript.ts#L169

**version 6 and earlier**:

You could use the property rawAttributes from the model. In your case User.rawAttributes would give you the properties wanted.

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/505467bd7fb66a0fe3298038307390c597500689/src/model.js#L321

Answer (score 1):

You may also get the data types from `Model.describe()`

```js
const User = sequelize.model(`User`)
const description = await User.describe()
    .then(data => {
        const res = []
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
            res.push({
                key,
                type: value.type
            })
        }
        return res
    })
console.log(description)
```

the output would be similar to:

```js
[
  { key: 'id', type: 'INTEGER' },
  { key: 'name', type: 'CHARACTER VARYING(255)' },
  { key: 'location', type: 'CHARACTER VARYING(255)' },
  { key: 'value', type: 'CHARACTER VARYING(255)' },
  { key: 'createdAt', type: 'TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE' },
  { key: 'updatedAt', type: 'TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE' }
]
```